# make observable wait until event N has reached the subscriber before emitting event N+1

Tags: java, rx-java, reactive-programming, rx-java2, vert.x

I've inherited an observable chain in vertx where we:

- periodically emit
- look up some state
- look up a second set of state
- write back a different version of the first state

It looks a bit like this:

```
Scheduler defaultScheduler = RxHelper.scheduler(vertx);
Scheduler blockingScheduler = RxHelper.blockingScheduler(vertx)
Observable.interval(/* some time */)
          .observeOn(blockingScheduler)
          .flatMapIterable(t -> getRecords())
          .observeOn(defaultScheduler)
          .flatMap(record -> Observable.just(record)
                                       .flatMap(getRecordDetails(record))
                                       .observeOn(blockingScheduler)
                                       .doOnNext(sendRecordDetails(detail))
                                       .observeOn(defaultScheduler)
                                       .doOnNext(markDetailAsSeenInLocalCache(detail))
                                       .onErrorReturn(e -> false)
                                       .all(success -> success)))
          .doOnNext(persistLocalCacheToJsonFileOnDisk())
          .subscribe( m -> {/* nothing */}, e -> {/* handle fatal error */});
```

My problem is that if `getRecords()` is called for iteration N+1 before `sendRecordDetails()` is called for the last time for iteration N then we have race conditions.

I don't have an expert understanding of scheduling in Rx/vertx, but I think that if this was all on the `defaultScheduler` then this would *probably* be ok. However as we wonder off into blocking schedulers when we want to do asynchronous blocking IO this relinquishes the main event loop used by the `defaultScheduler` which means it will go away and start servicing the next event from the first `interval` observable.

In the worst case if in iteration N `sendRecordDetails()` were to hang for long periods then this could result in iteration N+1 being completed before iteration N.

I have to admit that my first instinct is "maybe we shouldn't be using Rx for this". But I've inherited this code and I need to at least try and see if there's an in-convention method of getting this guarantee before I can claim that it's a lost cause and needs a rewrite into a different style.

The closest idea I've thought of is to have the subscribe write to a concurrent queue, and replacing the initial interval with `zipWith(interval(/* some time */, observableWhichEmitsItemsFromConcurrentQueue)`. This seems a bit like I'm forcing the framework to do things it shouldn't though. Plus it looks like I'd have to implement the concurrent queue observable myself.

So my question is: what's the most reasonable way to force one observable not to emit event N+1 until the subscriber has been notified for the event N, or is that forcing the framework to do something that it shouldn't really do?

Edit:

This is an example of something that forces the event to reach the subscriber before issuing the next. Without the subject the sequence is `A,A1,A,A1,B,C,B,C`, with the subject the sequence is `A,A1,B,C,A,A1,B,C`. Have I got the use of the Subject (including serialization) right?

```
@Test
public void baz() throws InterruptedException {
    BlockingDeque<Object> blockingDequed = new LinkedBlockingDeque<>();
    Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
    Scheduler d = RxHelper.scheduler(vertx);
    Scheduler b = RxHelper.blockingScheduler(vertx);

    X x = new X();

    Subject<Object> publishSubject = PublishSubject.create();

    int blockTime = 1;
    Observable.zip(publishSubject.serialize(), Observable.range(1,2), (i, j) -> j)
            .observeOn(d)
            .doOnNext(i -> logWithName(i, "A"))
            .doOnNext(i -> block(blockTime)) //blocks for blockTime seconds
            .doOnNext(i -> logWithName(i, "A1"))
            .concatMap( j -> Observable.just(j).observeOn(d)
                    .doOnNext(i -> block(blockTime))
                    .doOnNext(i -> logWithName(i, "B"))
            )
            .observeOn(d)
            .doOnNext(i -> logWithName(i, "C"))
            .doOnNext(i -> publishSubject.onNext(new Object()))
            .doOnComplete(() -> blockingDequed.add(new Object()))
            .subscribe();
    publishSubject.onNext(new Object());

    blockingDequed.poll(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
}
```

Comment: This requires a strong coupling between the end-subscriber and the item generator. You have to create a feedback channel that is triggered by the subscriber. For example, a serialized `PublishSubject` onto which you `flatMap` the generation of an item and call `onNext` from the subscriber once the processing has been  done.

Comment: Thanks, PublishSubject at least gets me out of having to write my own observable.